# AsyncTask doInBackground returning a nullpointerexception when internet connection is failed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

After make connection check by DomenK i've got next errors and my try catch block look like this:

```
try
            {
               if (isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
                  updateJSONdata();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "shit happens", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               finish();
            }

01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.updateList(ReadComments.java:253)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.onPostExecute(ReadComments.java:317)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.onPostExecute(ReadComments.java:1)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-06 19:24:41.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My app works very well but when internet connection is broke while Async is working my app dies. Below is my logcat and async code block. Maybe somebody can help my how to make try catch block or something that will detect internet connection problem, cancel next job, auto return to first activity and toast simple info with internet connection problem.

AsyncTask

```
public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadComments.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("ŁADUJĘ LISTĘ SKLEPÓW");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            wczytajMape();
            idzDoPolozenia(52.249665, 21.012511, 10);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // we will develop this method in version 2

                updateJSONdata();


            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // we will develop this method in version 2
            updateList();
            ustawMape();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

    }
```

StackTrace:

```
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.updateJSONdata(ReadComments.java:195)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.doInBackground(ReadComments.java:294)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.doInBackground(ReadComments.java:1)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    ... 4 more
01-06 18:52:14.793: W/ResourceType(32139): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 2
01-06 18:52:14.793: W/ResourceType(32139): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
01-06 18:52:14.793: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(32139): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-06 18:52:14.813: W/ResourceType(32139): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 2
01-06 18:52:14.823: W/ResourceType(32139): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
01-06 18:52:14.823: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(32139): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-06 18:52:15.173: W/Ads(32139): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139): Activity com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afc3688 that was originally added here
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afc3688 that was originally added here
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:267)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments$LoadComments.onPreExecute(ReadComments.java:285)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.onResume(ReadComments.java:147)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2156)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-06 18:52:15.193: E/WindowManager(32139):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must fix your bug here:

```
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 18:52:14.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32139):    at com.flex.sklepik.ReadComments.updateJSONdata(ReadComments.java:195)
```

check what you are referencing in line: ReadComments.java:195, and make sure to check if it is null pointer.

I suppose you are getting empty string from server, remember that checking connection status is not enough, there can be other failures that can cause data to be wrong or empty. Server can be down, unreachable, or dns can be down, or server can return HTTP errors, .... You must handle all such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to check Internet Connectivity -

```
if(isInternetConnection(YourActivity.this){
     //do Internet Stuff
}
else{
     //No Network
}


public static boolean isInternetConnection(Context mContext) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable()
            && wifi.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        return true;
    } else if (null!=mobile && mobile.isAvailable()
            && mobile.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i got this method in my first activity and it check connection before start app, but when user open second activity, start AsyncTask and then connection is lost my app is fail. I don't know where exactly put connection detect in AsyncTask.

Comment: You need to surround updateJSONdata(); function with try/catch clause and as soon you receive Null pointer exception, you need to cancel your AsyncTask.

Comment: finish() method shouldn't cancel AsynsTask?

Comment: finish() causes your Activity to finish itself, to cancel AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Call like - 
asynctaskInstance.cancel(true);

Besides, take care of @marcin_j Comment, he has pointed the real error. You must handle it.

Answer (score 0):

try and catch  updateJSONdata();
Before running AsyncTask make sure that Internet is working fine.

```
try{
                updateJSONdata();

} catch(Exception e){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget declare on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler function than Kanaks is this one (for cheching wifi/3g states).

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = 
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

But we are not done here since we can get a wifi/3g signal but no recieved data packets. You need to catch that exception using try/catch statement with collaboration with the function I've provided.

```
try
{
   if (isNetworkAvailable(context)
      updateJSONData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Connection time out
}
```